# Filtering elements of a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

In my project I need to build a list of possible moves. I've already done that, but I need to filter the possible moves from previous moves. How can I do that?

From:

```
PossibleMoves = [(up,1,2),(down,2,4),(left,1,3)],
PreviousMoves = [(up,1,2),(down,2,4)].
```

To:

```
PossibleMovesLeft = [(left,1,3)].
```

I tried `delete`, `\+ memberchk`, without success. Maybe I did something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

This question is not really related to mazes, it's just about removing all elements in a list from another list. There's a predicate for that: [`subtract/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=subtract/3).

> **subtract(+Set, +Delete, -Result)**
>   Delete all elements in Delete from Set. Deletion is based on unification using memberchk/2.

Example usage:

```
?- subtract([1,2,5,4,3,5,4], [6,2,4], X).
X = [1, 5, 3, 5]
```

But if needed, it's really easy to roll your own version.

Comment: `subtract([X],[],[2]).` correctly succeeds with `X = 2` but `subtract([X],[1],[2]). `fails, whereas again `X = 2, subtract([X],[1],[2]).` succeeds.

Comment: @false I read the question to mean that both `Set` and `Delete` are already instantiated, so I don't see a problem with that. Should a different form be needed that allows to _produce_ `Set`, it shouldn't be too difficult to do so. What I tried to get across is that the core question is relatively simple — just remove all elements in one list from another list — and that the OP may be focusing too much on mazes (I removed that tag, as the question has nothing to do with mazes).

Comment: Then, write your assumptions into the answer. Do you think that a beginner is able to read all those assumptions between the lines?

Comment: @false I've edited my answer (and the original question as well, for formatting); better?

Comment: Where do you state your assumptions?

Comment: @false In the first line, I restate the question in my own words. If the OP disagrees, they can say so be commenting ion my answer. Any other reader will see that _that_ is the question I'm answering.